# Lightning out App error in callback function

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I had created a lightning component to upload multiple files with the help of this URL [how to create upload multiple file url](https://www.biswajeetsamal.com/blog/upload-multiple-files-using-lightning-file-upload-component/)

which is working fine in action button but when I try to call that component in my VF page having the issue of **Lightning out App error in callback function**

To use the lightning component in VF page I follow this URL:-
[how to call component in VF page](http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/08/19/display-lightning-component-visualforce-page/)

and here is my vf page code:-

```
<apex:includeLightning />
<div id="fileMultiContainer" />
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:UploadFileApplication", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:UploadFile",
          {},
          "fileMultiContainer",
           function(cmp) {
               component.set("v.recordId",'{!order.Id}');
            });
     });
 </script>
```

Can someone please help me where I did wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation: [Usage Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation)

> This component is not supported in Lightning Out or standalone apps,
>   and displays as a disabled input. Additionally, if the Don't allow
>   HTML uploads as attachments or document records security setting is
>   enabled for your organization, the file uploader cannot be used to
>   upload files with the following file extensions: .htm, .html, .htt,
>   .htx, .mhtm, .mhtml, .shtm, .shtml, .acgi, .svg. For more information,
>   see Upload and Share Files in Salesforce Help.

In short, below are not allowed:

1. Don't allow HTML uploads as attachments or document records security setting
2. Lightning Out or standalone apps - is not supported

You are using `lightning out` and so will not work

Answer (score 0):

lightning:fileUpload base component will not work in lightning out app, it is supported only in Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, Salesforce Mobile App.